# pass tableview cell data to another view controller without storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I have tableView which have a list of names
i want to pass the name of the tableView cell to another view controller
here I code in didSelectRow at indexpath

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! GrupChatViewController
    controller.groupName.text = cell.grupName.text!  // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
    
}
```

but my application crash reason -> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value  at line 4

Answer (score 0):

Call `loadViewIfNeeded`

```
controller.loadViewIfNeeded() 
controller.groupName.text = cell.grupName.text!
```

Comment: it works, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a variable in your destination controller and pass data to that variable and in your viewDidLoad assigned that value to your view

First, take a variable in your GrupChatViewController

```
var groupStr = String()
```

Then update your didSelect method of tableView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
   let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
   let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondViewController") as! GrupChatViewController
   controller.groupStr = cell.grupName.text?
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```

Then in your GrupChatViewController do like this

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      groupName.text = groupStr
}
```